# Nodejs auto sign in if exist cookie remember me

Tags: node.js, express

This is my code.

```
if (!req.user) {
      var remember_me = req.cookies.remember_me;
      if (remember_me) {
        // find users and auto login.
     }
 }
```

I use passport for Login. Thank you

Comment: I think that SoF is for asking questions, not FYIs. But you know what, I love what I just saw! Cool.